# Objects with transparent texture not always show transparency in 3dview

Tags: materials, texturing, 3d-view

For some reason objects don't show their transparency all the time.

In this image the circles in red are suposed to be transparent like the ones in green.

[image]

When I select the object in the back, all objects in front of it become opaque.

[image]

When I select the two objects that are opaque, then they become transparent as they sould be.

[image]

The display is in GLSL mode

These are the material and texture properties

[image]

[image]

I'm not worried about the final render, just the editing view. I would like to see the actual transparency at editing time only, because the scene is to be imported in a third party game engine.

Blender is v2.68

[This](http://www17.zippyshare.com/v/49026227/file.html) is the blend file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the object panel in the properties and check Transparency in Display tab for all object you want to see transparent. make sure that you have the correct object selected.

[image: transparency option]

Comment: I tried this, and while it does work, if you set multiple objects to display transparency there will be some strange things of certain objects being occluded and others not. (It all seems to depend on what object is selected)

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm finding this now, similar as you've described, with unselected objects appearing correctly partly obscured behind partly-transparent objects, when selected, the portion of the object behind the partly-transparent front object is entirely occluded. Weird. Using 2.74