# Transparent material showing as black when unselected

Tags: materials, 3d-view

I have two objects that have the same transparent material. One object looks fine no matter what, the other only looks transparent when it is selected (that is the only thing I'm changing, pressing 'a'). Any ideas why this is happening?

I've tried moving the light around and changing Shading to GLSL and flipping the normals (in edit mode ctrl-F).

[image] (disclaimer: this is a nude female character)

Selected:
[image]

Deselected:
[image]

Comment: For those sensitive to nudity, the fact that this character is nude might be more important than its gender. Also, please consider using [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to share your .blend files.

Answer (score 1):

[answer source](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/objects-with-transparent-texture-not-always-show-transparency-in-3dview?rq=1)

Go to the object panel in the properties and check Transparency in Display tab for all object you want to see transparent. make sure that you have the correct object selected.

[image]