# how to remove this black shadow from around a transparent texture

Tags: texturing, materials, objects, image, transparency

i have a transparent material for blush but the problem when i deselect it i get a black shadow around it i don't know what the reason so how to remove this shadow in material mode ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: what if you try to set Z or raytrace transparency?

Comment: @m.ardito im already did that

Comment: if you can, make a file copy, then delete everything except that object, then upload it on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the resulting link in your question...

Comment: @m.ardito after i deleted everything the problem gone so what's the problem ?

Comment: how could I know? try to share something which has the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i founded the solution here [link to source](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/objects-with-transparent-texture-not-always-show-transparency-in-3dview?rq=1)

> Go to the object panel in the properties and check Transparency in
>   Display tab for all object you want to see transparent. make sure that
>   you have the correct object selected.

[image]